# .NET databound lists

Tags: .net, drop-down-menu, databound-lists

Is there any way around the following?

I have a few dropdown lists bound to lookup tables in SQL Server.
Some old records imported from a previos version of the system won't open due to data in these fields not matching the current dropdown data.

Other than adding the old data to the lookup table (which I don't want to do), is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Clumsy but it works,

I catch the error when the page can't open due to the data not being in the dropdown any more, then:

```
list.Items.Insert(0, new_thing);
list.SelectedIndex = 0;
```